# ng-repeat loop through object is not behaving properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my Angularjs ng-repeat is have following only one object, fields are reduced actually i have more than 40 in this object. if i have 40 fields then 40 empty output is rendering (see below outout).

```
{"Name": "Raj", "Gender":"M", "Country": "India"} (ONLY ONE OBJECT)
```

**Angular View**

```
<table ng-repeat="emp in model.Employee">
<tr>
<td><strong>Name:</strong></td>
<td>{{emp.Name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Gender:</strong></td>
<td>{{emp.Gender}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Excepted output is

```
Name: Raj 
Gender: M
```

But the actual out put is rendering three time without value.

```
Name: 
Gender: 

Name: 
Gender: 

Name: 
Gender:
```

Comment: Also why `ng-repeat` on table?should be on `tr`.,

Comment: what is model.Employee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are iterating over an object instead of an array. So, the `ngRepeat` loop will run as many times as there are keys in your object. Since, there are three keys in the object, the loop is being run thrice. Also, `emp`(the iterable) is the key('Name', 'Gender', 'Country') instead of the complete object.

Change to :

```
[{"Name": "Raj", "Gender":"M", "Country": "India"}]
```

Comment: your is correct, when i run through chrome console i am getting correct result. then how to convert this to array value is coming from some other source?

Comment: Declare an empty array and push the object into it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use (key,value) for this purpose.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.controller('ctrl',['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.data ={"Name": "Raj", "Gender":"M", "Country": "India"};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<div class="item item-checkbox">
      <table >
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in data" ng-if="key != 'Country'">
  <td>{{key}}</td>
<td>{{value}}</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```